# Why does pressing Shift+F5 insert @ character in some text editors?

Tags: windows-7, windows, visual-studio-2010, matlab

While debugging in matlab (and sometimes in the code editors of other IDE's, such as Visual Studio 10) I noticed that sometimes pressing shift+F5 (keyboard shortcut for stop debugging) inserts the @ character in the code

This seems to happen at random and I can never recreate it when I want to
It's not a big problem but it is a bit of a nuisance

Is this really happening because of pressing shift+F5, or is it happening due to some other reason? Is there way to disable this?

Note (in case this information is relevant):
The test computer uses standard English keyboard layout with Korean IME installed, with the default input language set to English
The OS is Windows 7 Enterprise Korean Version, but interface has been changed to English with some language pack installs

Edit:
Also, this happens in IDE code editors, but I have never seen it happen in notepad, MS Word, etc

Comment: Why the Matlab tag?

Comment: Becasue I first noticed it happen in matlab; anyway, I can't think of a good tag for this problem, as I can't even recreate it at will

Comment: Then maybe mention that in the question, otherwise it would look like a VS problem. Does it also happen in other applications, e.g. the address bar of a browser, or the cmd window?

Comment: It is mentioned that I found it while debugging in Matlab, and like I said, I can't make it happen at will, either in matlab or other text editors, it just seems to happen randomly

Comment: Sorry, reading to fast...